# BaseAdapter onItemClick references old instance

Tags: android, baseadapter

I have a strange problem where in my BaseAdapter when onClick is called, the listData of the current instance is old if I call getItem(pos); inside the callback, if I call av.getAdapter().getItem(pos) I get the updated version of the item. After hours of debugging I am not getting why this could be, any ideas? Please see the code below, and specially the onItemClick callback:

```
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnItemClickListener, IToggleChanged {

private final List<IItem> mData;

public MyAdapter(final Context context) {
    super();
    mData = new ArrayList<>();
    initData(context);
}

private void initData(final Context context) {
    mData.add(...);
    updateDataSet();
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(final int position) {
    return mData.get(position).isEnabled();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(final int pos) {
    return mData.get(pos);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(final int pos) {
    return pos;
}

private View inflateView(final Context context, final int pos) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    return inflater.inflate(mData.get(pos).getLayoutId(), null);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int pos, final View view, final ViewGroup vg) {
    final View v = inflateView(vg.getContext(), pos);
    mData.get(pos).fillView(v);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> av, final View view, final int pos, final long id) {

    // Scenario: toggle is off, you turn it on, list items get enabled, you now click on them and nothing happens because mEnabled=false, despite
    // we set it to true in updateDataSet. Don't know why this method have an old instance of mData, with the second method below it works as expected.
    //final IItem item2 = getItem(pos);

    final IItem item1 = av.getAdapter().getItem(pos);
    if (item1.isEnabled()) {
        item1.onClick(view);
    }
}

/**
 * Updates Items enable/disable state.
 */
private void updateDataSet() {
    for (final IItem item : mData) {
        item.setEnable(...);
    }
}

@Override
public void toggleChanged() {
    updateDataSet();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Comment: listData means mData? and where are you updating the data? and where exactly is the call of old data?

Comment: I don't think the "SpamSettingsAdapter.isEnabled()" method  is called from your onItemClick(). Try to directly use mData instead to do "(CAST)getAdapter()". Another thing: why do a cast to ISpamSettingItem if the items are "IItems"? Maybe you have declared "setEnabled()" in both interfaces but them refers to different methods and/or variables.

Comment: I updated the code. Workflow: toggle is pressed -> toggleChanged() is called and updateDataSet sets the field mEnabled of the item to TRUE, I then tap on one of the list items, so onItemClick is called, in that method you see the call item1.isEnabled(), using the uncommented version isEnabled returns FALSE, using the current method returns TRUE.